# Transcoding HD RTP/UDP stream with FFMPEG

Tags: ffmpeg, hls

I've a Tera STI440 streamer with two inputs used (for TV channel streaming). When I watch the source stream it seems allright, but when I start FFMPEG transcoding, the image is going to collapse on random times (probably around every 5-15 sec). The transcoding is okay with SD 480P streams.

`ffprobe` one of my HD streams:

```
Input #0, rtp, from 'rtp://239.192.24.3:1234/':
  Duration: N/A, start: 18002.926656, bitrate: N/A
  Program 202 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : M5 HD
      service_provider: Magyar Televizio
    Stream #0:1: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt709, top first), 1440x1080 [SAR 4:3 DAR 16:9], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:0(hun): Audio: mp2 ([3][0][0][0] / 0x0003), 48000 Hz, stereo, s16p, 128 enter code herekb/s
```

`ffprobe` one of my SD stream (Which is working properly):

```
Input #0, rtp, from 'rtp://239.192.24.4:1234/':
  Duration: N/A, start: 51003.435044, bitrate: N/A
  Program 203 
    Metadata:
      service_name    : RTL Klub
      service_provider: Magyar RTL Telev�zi� Zrt.
    Stream #0:0: Video: h264 (High) ([27][0][0][0] / 0x001B), yuv420p(tv, bt470bg, top first), 720x576 [SAR 12:11 DAR 15:11], 25 fps, 25 tbr, 90k tbn, 50 tbc
    Stream #0:1(hun): Audio: aac_latm (HE-AAC) ([17][0][0][0] / 0x0011), 48000 Hz, stereo, fltp
```

I want to do a HLS stream so I ran this command for `ffmpeg`:

```
/usr/bin/ffmpeg -loglevel 16 -i rtp://239.192.24.3:1234/ -s pal -c:v libx264 -c:a libmp3lame -b:v 1000k -b:a 96k -ar 44100 -vf 'yadif=0:-1:1' -preset:v superfast -f hls -hls_time 7 -hls_list_size 10 -hls_wrap 10 -hls_base_url http://10.3.1.3:8080/ts/ -hls_segment_filename /tvman/hls_out/ts/M5_hq_%03d /tvman/hls_out/subplaylist/M5-hq.m3u8
```

I access the playlist file from NGINX but also tried Apache too.
[Here's some log from FFMPEG process (loglevel 16)](https://paste.ubuntu.com/24898982/)

I made some diagnostics:

- Looked for network traffic (it's around 60 Mbps, so it should be okay with a 100 Mbps ethernet
- CPU & RAM load allright
- I reduced the network traffic by turning off TV channel streams on streamer. It was around 6-7 Mbps.

If you need any more information, I'll provide it for you.